# Entropy and uncertainty principle

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle, equilibrium

I know that entropy depends on the total energy of a system. In the energy-time uncertainty, howeve, energy can be uncertain for an amount of time which is related to the uncertainty of energy by having their product bigger than or equal to the Plank constant divided be 2, i.e. the famous energy-time uncertainty. Now, is this time related in any way to the relaxation time that the system needs to reach equilibrium so that its energy state variable is well defined? Those two concepts seem related, but I'm not sure if I'm right.

Comment: How is entropy related to your question? Which entropy do you mean, thermodynamic entropy or information entropy?

Comment: A related question: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/60905/uncertainty-and-thermodynamics?rq=1

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I mean thermodynamic entropy. Entropy is relates to the question because the uncertainty principle allows the system to be in a superposition of states of widely separated energies, which would seem to imply that the state variable(energy) isn't defined until the system settles into an energy eigenstate, so I thought the two concepts are related. @JánLalinský